# Calling a method on an instance of a class that inherits an abstract class

Tags: angular, typescript, casting, angular9

I have this abstract class here:

```
export abstract class BaseStepComponent {
    /** base-step ctor */
    constructor() {

    }

    abstract getValue(): string;

}
```

And one component inheriting it:

```
export class SingleChoiceStepComponent extends BaseStepComponent {
    /** single-choice-step ctor */
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
    
    @ViewChild("itemList") itemList: ElementRef;

    getValue(): string {
        return this.itemList.nativeElement.value;
    }

}
```

I have a few of these components and they have different logic in `getValue()`

Somewhere else in my application, I have this member in a component:

```
stepItems: QueryList<any>;
@ViewChildren("stepItem") set stepItemsContent(content: QueryList<any>) {
    let items = content.toArray();
    if (items.length > 0) {
        this.stepItems = content;
    }
}
```

"Steps" are fields in a wizard (multi-page form) and the application doesn't really know the type of the "steps" rendered and how many of them (configurable by a admin UI), but they are all inheriting `BaseStepComponent`

Later on, I want to collect the values returned by `getValue()`, but I have the problem mentioned in the comment below.

```
let values: any[] = [];
this.stepItems.forEach(step => {
 let v = step.getValue(); //works in IDE, not at runtime, sadly.
  values.push({ key: step.key, value: v });
});
```

Due to the fact that `BaseStepComponent` is abstract, I can't do something like:

```
let instance = new BaseStepComponent();
instance = Object.assign(instance, step);
```

So I'm kind of stuck. Any idea how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like below,

```
export abstract class BaseStepComponent {
/** base-step ctor */
constructor() {}

abstract getValue(): string;
}

@Component({
 selector: "step1",
 template: `
 <h1>Step 1</h1>
 `,
 providers: [{ provide: BaseStepComponent, useExisting: Step1Component }]
})
export class Step1Component extends BaseStepComponent {
 @Input() name: string;

 getValue(): string {
  return "Step1Component";
 }
}

@Component({
 selector: "step2",
 template: `
 <h1>Step 2</h1>
 `,
 providers: [{ provide: BaseStepComponent, useExisting: Step2Component }]
})
export class Step2Component extends BaseStepComponent {
 @Input() name: string;

 getValue(): string {
  return "Step2Component";
 }
}
```

And to use it,

```
export class AppComponent {
  name = "Angular " + VERSION.major;

  @ViewChildren(BaseStepComponent) items: QueryList<BaseStepComponent>;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.items.map((step: BaseStepComponent) => {
      console.log(step.getValue());
    });
  }
}
```

here is the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-base-componets).

Comment: This is weird. It appears just explicitly typing the `step` parameter when looping does it. Thanks.